# Responsive full width svg logo

Tags: svg, responsive

So I have this logo that fits the whole page. Is there anyway that, when the browser is resized I can move these paths? That way the height stays the same?

[Example of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiXWe.png)

Here's my svg code

```
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
            viewBox="0 0 1440 52" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1440 52;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M1428.4,6.9c-2.5-2.5-6-3.7-10.5-3.7h-7.6h-9.5v19.1H16.3V3.1H7.8v46.8h8.5V30.7h1384.5v19.1h0h9.4V30.6h7.5
            c2.3,0,4.3-0.3,6-1c1.8-0.7,3.3-1.7,4.5-2.9c1.2-1.2,2.2-2.7,2.8-4.5c0.7-1.7,1-3.6,1-5.8C1432.2,12.1,1430.9,9.4,1428.4,6.9z
             M1421.4,20.1c-1,1-2.8,1.9-5.2,2h-6v-12h6c2.3,0,4,0.6,5.2,1.8s1.7,2.7,1.7,4.4C1423.1,18.5,1421.8,19.8,1421.4,20.1z" />
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this by using preserveAspectRatio="none" for the svg element together with a fixed height and width:100%. This would give tou what you need but the the stroke would be scaled differently on the vertical and horizontal.

To fix it you need to add vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" for the path.

```css
svg{height:100px; width:100%}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path stroke="black"  stroke-width="5" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M 1,5V15M1,10H97"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! I wasn't able to achieve it with my svg. I added everything you mentioned and it still deformed my svg. I added my svg code in the question but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, with a bit of trickery.  Below is a modified verion of your SVG that behaves how you want.

This matches your SVG exactly, but has a limitation.  The trick we are using relies on extending the middle bar a long way to the left. Then covering up the left end of the bar with your vertical piece.  But in your original SVG the vertical piece is not right at the left end of your SVG. So I've had to hide some of the extension with a white rectangle. This assumes your background will also be white. If it isn't you'll need to change that white rectangle to be the same colour as your page background.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="52">
  <defs>
    <path id="middle-and-right" transform="translate(-1440 0)"
          d="M1428.4,6.9c-2.5-2.5-6-3.7-10.5-3.7h-7.6h-9.5v19.1
             h -3000 v 8.4 h 3000
             v19.1h0h9.4V30.6h7.5 c2.3,0,4.3-0.3,6-1c1.8-0.7,3.3-1.7,4.5-2.9c1.2-1.2,2.2-2.7,2.8-4.5c0.7-1.7,1-3.6,1-5.8C1432.2,12.1,1430.9,9.4,1428.4,6.9z
             M1421.4,20.1c-1,1-2.8,1.9-5.2,2h-6v-12h6c2.3,0,4,0.6,5.2,1.8s1.7,2.7,1.7,4.4C1423.1,18.5,1421.8,19.8,1421.4,20.1z" />
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href="#middle-and-right" x="100%"/>
  <rect x="-1" y="3.1" width="10" height="46.8" fill="white"/>
  <rect x="7.8" y="3.1" width="8.5" height="46.8"/>
</svg>
```

If you want to get a better idea how the trick works, have a look at this version. I've modified the SVG to make the trick more apparent.

```css
svg {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: visible;
}

rect {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="52">
  <defs>
    <path id="middle-and-right" transform="translate(-1440 0)"
          d="M1428.4,6.9c-2.5-2.5-6-3.7-10.5-3.7h-7.6h-9.5v19.1
             h -3000 v 8.4 h 3000
             v19.1h0h9.4V30.6h7.5 c2.3,0,4.3-0.3,6-1c1.8-0.7,3.3-1.7,4.5-2.9c1.2-1.2,2.2-2.7,2.8-4.5c0.7-1.7,1-3.6,1-5.8C1432.2,12.1,1430.9,9.4,1428.4,6.9z
             M1421.4,20.1c-1,1-2.8,1.9-5.2,2h-6v-12h6c2.3,0,4,0.6,5.2,1.8s1.7,2.7,1.7,4.4C1423.1,18.5,1421.8,19.8,1421.4,20.1z" />
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href="#middle-and-right" x="100%"/>
  <rect x="-1" y="3.1" width="10" height="46.8" fill="white"/>
  <rect x="7.8" y="3.1" width="8.5" height="46.8"/>
</svg>
```

**However** if you don't mind the vertical piece on the left end being moved so it's hard up against the left side of the SVG, then we can remove that restriction regarding the background. The new version below will work for any page background colour.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="52">
  <defs>
    <path id="middle-and-right" transform="translate(-1440 0)"
          d="M1428.4,6.9c-2.5-2.5-6-3.7-10.5-3.7h-7.6h-9.5v19.1
             h -3000 v 8.4 h 3000
             v19.1h0h9.4V30.6h7.5 c2.3,0,4.3-0.3,6-1c1.8-0.7,3.3-1.7,4.5-2.9c1.2-1.2,2.2-2.7,2.8-4.5c0.7-1.7,1-3.6,1-5.8C1432.2,12.1,1430.9,9.4,1428.4,6.9z
             M1421.4,20.1c-1,1-2.8,1.9-5.2,2h-6v-12h6c2.3,0,4,0.6,5.2,1.8s1.7,2.7,1.7,4.4C1423.1,18.5,1421.8,19.8,1421.4,20.1z" />
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href="#middle-and-right" x="100%"/>
  <rect x="0" y="3.1" width="8.5" height="46.8"/>
</svg>
```